# countably compact KC space

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

A space is said to have the finite derived set property if each infinite subset $A
\subset X$ contains an infinite subset with only finitely many accumulation points in $X$.

> **A countably compact KC space of cardinality less than c has the FDS property.**
>
> **To see it** : suppose $X$ satisfies the hypothesis. since every countably compact of cardinality than c is sequentially compact, so $X$ is sequentially compact.. Thus for any infinite subset $A \subset X$, we assume without loss of generality that $A = \{ x_n : n \in \omega$, then $A$ must have a sequence $ \{ x_{n_{k}} : k = 1, 2....\}$ s.t $x_{n_{k}} \longrightarrow‎ x, k \longrightarrow‎ \infty‎$.Thus $ \{ x_{n_{k}} : k = 1, 2....\} \cup \{ x \}$ is compact and closed in $X$, so $x$ is the unique accumulation point of $ \{ x_{n_{k}} : k = 1, 2....\}$ . So $X$ has FDS - property.

I need some more comment about:

> $x$ is the **unique** accumulation point of $ \{ x_{n_{k}} : k = 1, 2....\}$. **Why**?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=\{x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. $S\cup\{x\}$ is closed in $X$, so no point of $X\setminus(S\cup\{x\})$ is an accumulation point of $S$. Thus, either $x$ is the only accumulation point of $S$, or there is an $\ell\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_{n_\ell}$ is an accumulation point of $S$. Let $K=\{x_{n_k}:k>\ell\}\cup\{x\}$. The sequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k>\ell\rangle$ converges to $x$, so $K_0$ is compact for the same reason that $S\cup\{x\}$ is. $X$ is $KC$, so $K$ is closed in $X$. But then $X\setminus K$ is an open nbhd of $k_{n_\ell}$ containing only finitely many points of $S$. Finally, every $KC$ space is $T_1$, so $(X\setminus K)\setminus\{x_{n_k}:k<\ell\}$ is an open nbhd of $x_{n_\ell}$ containing no other point of $S$, and $x_{n_\ell}$ is therefore not an accumulation point of $S$. Thus, $x$ is the only accumulation point of $S$.